# Moving Access update query to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-update

We are migrating a Access database to Azure, one update queries is not working despite trying several syntax changes and removals of spaces.

Below is the design view of the query in Access:
[Query Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ubdf.jpg)

The following is the SQL expression of the update query in Access:

```
UPDATE SPEND_steve, KeywordRULES 
SET SPEND_steve.Category = [KeywordRULES].Category
WHERE (((SPEND_steve.Category) Is Null) AND ((SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like "*" 
And (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription)=[KeywordRULES].[ItemDescription] 
And (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like "*"));
```

With the above I receive `error 102: Incorrect syntax near ','.`

Thank you in advance for any help to move this functioning query from Access to SQL server!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ", KeywordRULES" from Line 1, an [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement is only able to update one table (or view) at a time.

```
UPDATE SPEND_steve 
SET SPEND_steve.Category = 
[KeywordRULES].Category WHERE (((SPEND_steve.Category) Is Null) AND 
((SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like "" And (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription)=
[KeywordRULES].[ItemDescription] And (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like "")) ;
```

Comment: SQLOnly, thank you i've pulled that from the update line now your comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Update syntax is a bit different to Access, in that each update statement should affect a single table.  You can however reference other tables through a join or other ways depending on what you are trying to do.

So KeywordRules is implicitly joined in your query.  So your intention is to update the SPEND_steve table based on info from the KeywordRules table.  You can do this by a join to the keyword rules.

```
Update SPEND_steve
Set SPEND_steve.Category = [KeywordRULES].Category WHERE
(((SPEND_steve.Category) Is Null) AND ((SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like ""
And (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription) Like "")) 
JOIN KeywordRules on (SPEND_steve.ItemDescription)=[KeywordRULES].[ItemDescription];
```

Also you should change `like ""` to `= ""` which may yeild a performance increase, although you might want to check for `AND IS Not NULL` as well if it could be null.

Comment: Spence thank you *very* much!  You have me pointed in a better direction,  I need to spend more time with SQL to get the syntax right but i'm hopeful to have it running soon.

Comment: You're new here.  You need to press the little arrow on the answer to say you liked it, and click the tick if the answer solved your problem.